# csv export with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, csv, coffeescript

I'm trying to export List on Rails as csv. I'm using the daterangepicker to select the date and then export the list using JQuery but whenever I press the export button the page just refreshes... In the debugging mode I can see that it goes through the code but at the end of the function nothing happens...

here is my coffeescript code

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

if gon.current_controller == 'measurements'
  $ ->
    # Search functionality
    $('form.measurement.search [name=daterange]').daterangepicker({
        format: gon.js_formats.moment.date,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
           'This Week': [moment().startOf('week'), moment().endOf('week')],
           'Last Week': [moment().subtract('week', 1).startOf('week'), moment().subtract('week', 1).endOf('week')],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
        },
        startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
        endDate: moment()
      },
      (start, end) -> $('form.measurement.search').submit());

    $('form.measurement input,select').change (ev) ->
      $('form.measurement.search').submit()

    $('form.measurement [name=clear]').click (ev) ->
      $('form.measurement.search [name=daterange]').val('')
      $('form.measurement.search').submit()
      false

    # CSV export
    $('form.measurement [name=format_csv]').click (ev) ->
      form = $(ev.target).closest('form')
      $('[name=format]', form).val('csv').prop('disabled', false)
      form.submit()
      $('[name=format]', form).val('').prop('disabled', true)
      false
```

here is how I call the function:

```
<%= submit_tag "Export CSV", name: :format_csv, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

and here is my controller:

```
class MeasurementsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /measurements
  include MeasurementsHelper
  def index
    @channel_name = Channel.find(params[:channel_id]).try(:label)
    @measurements = filter_measurements_by_params(Measurement.where(channel_id: params[:channel_id]).order('measured_at DESC'))
     @users = User.select(:id, :username, :name)

    @total =  @measurements.length
    @measurements = @measurements.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.csv { render csv: @measurements }
    end
  end

  def show
    @measurement = Measurement.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @measurement }
    end
  end

  # GET /measurements/new
  def new
    @measurement = Measurement.new(channel_id: params[:channel_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
    end
  end

  # POST /measurements
  def create
    params[:measurement][:user_id] = current_user.id
    params[:measurement][:channel_id] = params[:channel_id]
    @measurement = Measurement.new(measurement_params_create)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @measurement.save
        format.html { redirect_to channel_measurements_url(@measurement.channel), notice: 'Measurement was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /measurements/1
  def destroy
    @measurement = Measurement.find(params[:id])
    channel = @measurement.channel
    @measurement.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to channel_measurements_url(channel), notice: 'Measurement was successfully deleted.' }
    end
  end

  private
    def measurement_params_create
      params.require(:measurement).permit(:value, :channel_id, :user_id, :measured_at)
    end
end
```

I hope somebody can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

i forgot to add the hidden field tags to the html.

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag 'authenticity_token', form_authenticity_token.to_s, disabled: true %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'format', nil, disabled: true %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'description', nil, disabled: true %>
```